# Why is ORDER BY LIMIT 1 so much faster than MAX?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, aggregate, order-by

Here are my two queries:

```
select sts_in 
from sta_session 
where sts_user_id=2006 
AND sts_sessid!='0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6' 
order by sts_in desc limit 1;
```

And

```
select max(sts_in) 
from sta_session 
where sts_user_id=2006 
AND sts_sessid!='0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6';
```

For reference, the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sta_session` (
    `sta_session_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sts_sessid` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'PHP session ID',
    `sts_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `sts_in` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `sts_out` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `sts_ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `sts_browser_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`sta_session_id`),
    KEY `sts_sessid` (`sts_sessid`),
    KEY `sts_user_id` (`sts_user_id`),
    KEY `sts_ip` (`sts_ip`),
    KEY `fk_sta_browser_id` (`sts_browser_id`),
    KEY `idx_last_login` (`sts_user_id`,`sts_in`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If I run explain on both the queries, the first one (with order by) uses my special index that I created just for this query, `idx_last_login`, but the other one uses `sts_user_id`.

Can the MAX query *not* take advantage of `idx_last_login`? Why not?

I know it can *use* that index, because I can force it, but I suspect it's ignoring the `sts_in` part of it and just searching by user id.

---

The EXPLAINs, in JSON format for easy reading.

```
explain select sts_in from sta_session where sts_user_id=2006 AND sts_sessid!='0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6' order by sts_in desc limit 1;

[{
  "id": 1,
  "select_type": "SIMPLE",
  "table": "sta_session",
  "type": "ref",
  "possible_keys": "sts_sessid,sts_user_id,idx_last_login",
  "key": "idx_last_login",
  "key_len": "4",
  "ref": "const",
  "rows": 723106,
  "Extra": "Using where"
 }
]


explain select max(sts_in) from sta_session where sts_user_id=2006 AND sts_sessid!='0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6';

[{
  "id": 1,
  "select_type": "SIMPLE",
  "table": "sta_session",
  "type": "ref",
  "possible_keys": "sts_sessid,sts_user_id,idx_last_login",
  "key": "sts_user_id",
  "key_len": "4",
  "ref": "const",
  "rows": 723107,
  "Extra": "Using where"
 }
]
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of the index you created (`idx_last_login`)

Comment: How much time does each query need to run?

Comment: @JoishiBodio It's in the create sql no? It's a compound index on `(sts_user_id, sts_in)`.

Comment: @ypercube Order by takes 0.001s and MAX takes 18.2s on my test DB with 727K records.

Comment: Please add in the question, the `EXPLAIN` output for both queries.

Comment: This makes not sense to me.  I know it can use that index, because I can force it, but I suspect it's ignoring the sts_in part of it and just searching by user id.  If the give the same answer they are searching the same stuff.

Comment: Also remove your simple quotes in `sts_user_id='2006'` please, you're filtering a `INTERGER` field, you don't need those quotes because they are the same data type.

Comment: @ypercube Added the EXPLAINs.

Comment: @Blam Searching the same stuff, but in a different manner. Without indexes, MAX() is O(n) -- it scans through everything once keeping track of the MAX. Perhaps MySQL is too dumb to utilize the index, or there's some subtle difference between these queries that I just can't see.

Comment: @oNare My query builder is adding those because the user ID is stored as a string, but I can strip those.

Comment: So, basically the question is not why the 1st query is so much faster than the 2nd (we know why, it uses a different index) but why the optimizer chooses different indexes for the queries. And by the way, which version of mysql do you use?

Comment: @ypercube No. Even if I add `force index (idx_last_login)` to the max query, it's *still* slower. We're using MySQL 5.6.22.

Answer (score 7):

It makes a lot of sense to me.

The MySQL Query Optimizer looks over the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Look at the first query

```
select sts_in 
from sta_session 
where sts_user_id=2006 
AND sts_sessid!='0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6' 
order by sts_in desc limit 1;
```

Which index in `sta_session` has the most columns mentioned in the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` clauses ? `idx_last_login`

How does MySQL locate the MAX value ?

- Traverse `sts_user_id` in `idx_last_login` index for 2006
- Go to the Last Index Entry for `sts_in` for `sts_user_id` 2006
- Scroll backwards until `sts_sessid!='0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6'`
- Limit result to 1 row

Look at the second query

```
select max(sts_in) 
from sta_session 
where sts_user_id=2006 
AND sts_sessid!='0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6';
```

Which index in `sta_session` has the most columns mentioned in the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` clauses ? Not `idx_last_login`, but `sts_user_id`.

How does MySQL locate the MAX value ?

- Full Index Range Scan `sts_user_id` for 2006
- Aggregate `sts_in` from the table, comparing all values of `sts_sessid` <> `'0jitkt80gg3avere03tqk4lhi6'`

## POSSIBLE WORKAROUND

Since `sts_user_id` and `idx_last_login` are duplicate indexes (because they have the same first column), you should run

```
ALTER TABLE sta_session DROP INDEX sts_user_id;
```

There is a possibility for `idx_last_login` to be chosen and aggregate `sts_in`. However, there is still some traversal across the table.

If you really want to get aggressive with indexing, create this one

```
ALTER TABLE sta_session ADD INDEX everything_and_the_kitchen_sink_index
(sts_user_id,sts_in,sts_sessid);
```

This index might get selected and never have to touch the table because all columns (`WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `MAX()`) are in the index.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: I created `everything_and_the_kitchen_sink_index` without dropping `idx_last_login`. It still chose `idx_last_login`. I don't think indexes [help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6104628/65387) for `!=` queries. Why wouldn't MySQL look at the `SELECT` clause? I thought it did -- I thought it could pull certain values right out of the index without even touching the main table?